# Поговорка для "либо одно либо другое"

Tags: лексика, фразеология

Два почти несовместимых качества, и нужно предложить выбор наподобие:
либо дешево, либо качественно;
либо красивый муж, либо верный муж;
либо одно, либо другое.

Какая крылатая фраза или поговорка приходит вам в голову?

**P.S.** Интересуют равноправные качества, среди которых не выделяется один, явно предпочтительный, вариант.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть хочется... худеть хочется...
(фильм "Раба любви")

Comment: У кого это было: "Если жениться, то на женщине, тут выбора нет.  Но, вот на какой, на умной или, наоборот, красивой?"

Answer (score 1):

Ну , лично мне "пришли в голову" только две поговорки . 1. **Или пан - или пропал .** ("Пан" здесь в смысле "хозяин положения" , "лидер" , "победитель" , "вознаграждённый" .) 2. **Либо грудь в крестах - либо голова в кустах .** (Появилась в 1МВ . "Кресты" это ордена "Георгиевский крест" , а "кусты" сажали на могиле в месте расположения головы похороненного , где ставился и памятник .)

Comment: Спасибо! Подобных поговорок я вспомнила много, например: 
Либо хорошего коня держать, либо плеть. 
Либо в сук, либо в тетерю. 
Либо полковник, либо покойник.
Но они все мне не вполне подходят: здесь либо выиграл, либо проиграл. А мне нужно либо яблоко либо груша, когда хочется и то и другое.

Answer (score 0):

Либо полон двор, либо с корнем вон.

Comment: Спасибо! Но здесь один из вариантов явно предпочтительнее. А у меня варианты равноправные, но взаимоисключающие.

Answer (score -1):

Либо рыбку съесть, либо на мель сесть.